# Tree of files with vertical lines in PhpStorm

Tags: ide, phpstorm

Ho to make tree of files with vertical lines in PhpStorm for navigation in project?

[image: tree_of_files]

Comment: IDE version? Since 2018.1 -- not possible. Maybe (big maybe) they will make it for 2018.3 or so. https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185538 and https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165101

Comment: 2018.1.5. I understand, thanks for the links

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no previous Windows GUI theme since 2018.1. JetBrains have made their own Windows theme that follows modern MS guidelines (e.g. Windows 10 look alike) and dotted tree lines is not there (as well as bigger spacing between elements etc).

I suggest following these tickets (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress. As it stands right now some improvements in this area are expected only for 2018.3 version or later.

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-185538
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-165101